# Box dimension, graphs and sum of functions

Tags: real-analysis, fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

Let $f,g:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ be two continuous functions,

Is it true that $dim_B(graph(f+g))\le \max\{\dim_B(graph(f)),dim_B(graph(g))\}$?

It is well known (in Falconer book is an exercise) that this is even an equality if both dimensions are not equal. 
I am specially interested in the case that both dimensions are the same.
It is trivial that, in this last case, $f+g$ can be zero (just take $g=-f$) or any Lipschitz function.

So my more specific question is the next:

If $f,g:[0,1]\to{\mathbb R}$ are continuous functions whose graphs have Box-dimension $s$, 
¿Is $dim_B(graph(f+g))\le s$?

Also interested, if possible, in lower and upper box-dimension.

Comment: Is this not an immediate consequence of your first assertion?

Comment: No. I am asking both.
A positive answer to the first one, would imply a positive answer to the second.
In fact, due to the comment about different box-dimensios, a positive answer to the second one, would imply a positive answer to the first one.

Comment: So, "It is true that" should be "Is it true that"?

Comment: Yes!!! Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question appears as lemma 3.4 of my paper ["The prevalent dimension of graphs"](https://marksmath.org/scholarship/prevfunc.pdf). The proof states that this is a simple consequence of the inequality
$$R_{f+g}[a,b] \leq R_f[a,b] + R_g[a,b] \leq 
2\max\{R_f[a,b],R_g[a,b]\},$$
where $R_{f}[a,b] = \sup\{|f(x) - f(y)|:a<x,y<b\}$.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the answer and the reference!!!!